# How do I get Google Places API to return types from Table 1?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

I have some data on buildings that I need to categorise into 'types'.

The code works, but the type returned is from Table 2 from here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types - I want the types from Table 1.

```
searchBase = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input="
detailsBase = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id="

query = "Cambridge City Council Ditchburn Place Cambridge"
query = query.replace(" ", "%20")

inp = "&inputtype=textquery"
fields = "&fields=formatted_address,name,place_id,type"
detailsFields = "&fields=place_id,name,permanently_closed,type,url"
api = f"&key={api_key}"

r = requests.get(searchBase+query+inp+fields+api)

json.loads(r.text)
```

Which gives me the response:

```
{'candidates': [{'formatted_address': 'City Council, Ditchburn Pl, Cambridge CB1 2DR, United Kingdom',
   'name': 'Ditchburn Place',
   'place_id': 'ChIJyYr96YVw2EcRz-VfG7alOHQ',
   'types': ['point_of_interest', 'establishment']}],
 'status': 'OK'}
```

'point_of_interest' and 'establishment' are types from Table 2.

I also tried returning the type using the Place ID from the first output, but I have the same problem. And I have also used 'types' instead of 'type' in the request but it made no difference.

```
place = json.loads(r.text)['candidates'][0]['place_id']
detail = requests.get(detailsBase+place+detailsFields+api)
json.loads(detail.text)
```

Response:

```
{'html_attributions': [],
 'result': {'name': 'Ditchburn Place',
  'place_id': 'ChIJyYr96YVw2EcRz-VfG7alOHQ',
  'types': ['point_of_interest', 'establishment'],
  'url': 'https://maps.google.com/?cid=8374625708657337807'},
 'status': 'OK'}
```

Comment: @chrc What type from *Table 1* would you be expecting to receive for *Cambridge City Council*? Maybe `local_government_office`? In any case, this all depends on how the given place was categorized. When I check the address you provided as an example, I see nothing on the map. Is this place an active/open place? When I search for other local city offices in Cambridge, they do show some types from *Table 1*. Make sure you are using the right place ID!

Comment: Thank you everyone. I managed to get in touch with Google and it turned out the building I was using as a test (Cambridge City Council) just happened to return types from table 1 only.     When I classified the whole dataset it returned a mix of types from tables 1 and 2, which turns out to be the ideal output for my purposes.

Comment: To illustrate what I said above, place ID `ChIJcY1Fmb1w2EcR7hc57EtTrps` which refers to *Cambridge City Council Customer Service Centre, Peas Hill, Cambridge* returns `["local_government_office", "point_of_interest", "establishment"]` while place ID `ChIJ-c6PZpdw2EcRXY_X69XKPyc` which refers to *Cambridge City Council Customer Service Centre, Regent Street, Cambridge* returns `["point_of_interest", "establishment"]`.